# How to extend generic Java class in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2

I have Scala class and I would like to extend one of the generic classes of JavaFX to create my custom contro

```
public abstract class SkinBase <C extends Control, B extends BehaviorBase <C>> 
                               extends StackPane 
                               implements Skin <C>
```

but I can't. example:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Control

class MyControl extends Control {

}

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase

class MyControlSkin extends SkinBase[MyControl,MyControlBehavior] {

}

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase

class MyControlBehavior extends BehaviorBase[MyControl] {

}
```

Any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: Does `MyControlBehavior` extend `BehaviorBase[MyControl]` like it's supposed to?

Comment: Yes, it does. MyControlBehavior extend BehaviorBase[MyControl] like it's supposed to but there is also error message like in MyControlSkin -  Unspecified value parameters: : C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class MyControlBehavior(myControl: MyControl) extends BehaviorBase[MyControl](myControl)
```